# How to rename all symbols using Roslyn?

Tags: refactoring, rename, roslyn, automated-refactoring

I'm building a Standalone app which will load a folder with c# code, and allow the user to write Regex to select and rename namespace/types/fields/properties/methods/argument/variable/events'name, but i'm stuck at renaming source code.
I have analyzed the SyntaxTree and collected all items, and also searched/matched/renamed with regex.

I have done a plenty of codes trying to get roslyn rename "items", but i only the first "item" is renamed while all the next ones are discarded.
I am aware of Immutability of the Syntax API, and after calling Renamer I save the solution, and also re-search the document in the new solution in the next loop.

```
//renaming code
var newSolution = await Renamer.RenameSymbolAsync(solution, isymbol, newName, solution.Workspace.Options).ConfigureAwait(false);
this.solution = newSolution;

//re-search code
if (solution.Projects.First ().ContainsDocument(doc.Document.Id)) {
    var document = project.GetDocument(doc.Document.Id);
    ...
}
```

At the end i call SyntaxTree.GetRoot().ToString (); to get the final edited code, which as mentioned above has only the first edit.

Could anyone explain me the correct way to do this or provide me a sample how this could be implemented so i can try on my own?

Comment: I would need to see a complete sample to figure out what is wrong

Comment: @Jonathon Download Link: [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar0JOliH3ShIgQjIYpXDdi_SU2bT?e=IVcx2u)
Steps to use this project
1. Open Roslyn Refactory - V2\Roslyn Refactory\bin\Debug\Roslyn Refactor.exe
1.1 (skip the messagebox which was added only to learn a code i've found on the net)

2. Click File > Open Solution and load any .sln file

3. In the right bottom TreeView select a file you want to open
3.1 (press ok to the messagebox to proceed)

4. Click Edit > Rename